# Escaping user input for use in a PostgreSQL regex using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, postgresql, escaping, pcre

I'm creating a regular expression pattern to be matched with `~` or `~*`, where part of the pattern is created by the application and part is taken from user input:

```
$userInput = "t ' e * \\s * t ( i \n g";

$pattern = "(a|b|c)" . preg_quote($userInput) . "(x|y|z)";
$pattern = pg_escape_literal($conn, $pattern);

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM example WHERE name ~* $pattern");
```

This works, so far, but I'm not completely sure about its safety:

- Does PHP's `preg_quote()` escape (at least) all the special characters in a PostgreSQL regular expression?
- Is there any possible `$userInput` value that could break the escaping?

*(There is some generic processing for `$userInput` before it reaches this stage - encoding, charset, accepted character ranges, etc. Query parameters are used for most of the (actual) query, but this part of the SQL is created manually.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html), `~` and `~*` use POSIX regular expressions, which means that these characters are treated specially:

```
()[]{}^$|?:.\
```

`preg_quote`, from [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), just blindly goes through and puts a backslash (i.e. escapes) all of these characters:

```
.\+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:-
```

In other words, it escapes all of the characters that need escaping.

However, you should still be careful. If you decide to use `LIKE` or `SIMILAR TO` at some point in the future, `_` and `%` won't be escaped. Also, you have to remember not to use a different escape character; if you do, all that careful validation will go out the window, and you'd get a host of weird bugs.